# Matching the same word twice with a regular expression, not caring what the word is

Tags: javascript, regex

Take the following input:

```
foo.foo aefhiuafhiauefheiauh bar.bar jgoeiajgoieajogiae baz.foo ogiejaogijaeoigjea
```

Say I want to match `x.x` where x is the same both sides of the dot. So I don't want to match `x.y`. So with the example input, I'd get `foo.foo`, `bar.bar` and not `baz.foo`

What I want to do is something like

```
(\w+)\.$1
```

But of course that doesn't work.

Is this possible in any sane way with a regex, or should I be matching `x.y` and handling the comparison of `x` and `y` in code?

For the sake of the question, assume I'm using the Javascript regex engine.

Comment: Have you tried (\w+)\.\1 http://rubular.com/r/yXdlTXD6Uy

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(\w+)\.\1/g
```

This uses the `\1` [backreference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#backreferences) to match the text of first capturing group `(\w+)`.

Tested on http://regexpal.com/ and works.

Comment: Yup. Works fine. You are a gentleman and a scholar. I can't accept the answer for 9 minutes but when I can, I shall.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html doesn't show all matches!

Comment: For those who don't know what `\1` is: it's called **Back Reference**

Comment: @Emadpres Enhanced the answer to explain the backreference

Answer (score 6):

Should be with global!

```
/(\w+)\.\1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing an adaptation to the accepted answer for people using Visual Studio 2017 to find the same variable name repeated in the same line.

The search I used is:

```
(\w+) = \1 [&]
```

I was searching for VB string concatenations where I want to consider replacing them with either stringbuilder or the simplified &= operator so I wanted to replace:

```
MyString = MyString & something
```

with

```
MyString &= something
```

The expression works with find all so I was able to find all instances

Comment: Strangely it also finds msLog = sLog & vbCrLf & msLog - thats because sLog matched \w+ I guess