# Removing duplicated img tags using php

Tags: php, string

In a string like this:

```
<body>
   <img src="specialpic" />
   <p>sometext</p><br>
   <img src="/somepic.png" />
   <img src="/somepic.png" />
   <p>someotherstuff</p>
   <img src="/anotherpic.png" />
   <img src="/anotherpic.png" />
</body>
```

How do I remove every duplicated `img` tag, so that the final string would look like below?

```
<body>
   <img src="specialpic" />
   <p>sometext</p><br>
   <img src="/somepic.png" />
   <p>someotherstuff</p>
   <img src="/anotherpic.png" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HTML parser for this. See this example with `DOMDocument`.

Init `DOMDocument` and load your HTML file:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);
$dom->formatOutput = True;

$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Init two empty array: `$img` will contains unique `src` values, `$toDelete` will contains duplicated nodes to delete:

```
$img = $toDelete = array();
```

Search for all node with `<img>` tag:

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
```

For each found node, compare `src` attribute with `$img` array: if it is found, add current node to `$toDelete`, otherwise add `src` value to `$img`:

```
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $src = $node->getAttribute('src' );
    if( in_array( $src, $img ) ) $toDelete[] = $node;
    else                         $img[] = $src;
}
```

At the end, perform a `foreach` loop to delete nodes found:

```
foreach( $toDelete as $node ) $node->parentNode->removeChild( $node );
```

To print resulting HTML:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Please note the usage of `$toDelete` array. Theoretically we could delete nodes directly inside first `foreach`, but by this way we reduce the len of original found set, so next node is skipped.

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- Read **[why you can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262)**

Comment: Is there a faster way?? maybe with some php string functions?

Comment: You can (not) use regular expression, but with HTML the best way is ever through a parser, otherwise you will have unexpected results. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262)

Answer (score 1):

While not entirely recommended due to the nature of HTML, according to your question, and assuming that the image tags are always in the same format, or exactly the same characters to characters when compared, this is possible with sub pattern.

Try this:

```
$input =<<<EOF
<body>
<img src="specialpic" />
<p>sometext</p><br>
<img src="/somepic.png" />
<img src="/somepic.png" />
<p>someotherstuff</p>
<img src="/anotherpic.png" />
<img src="/anotherpic.png" />
</body>
EOF;

$result = preg_replace('|(<img\s*src=.*?\s*/>\s*)\1*|s', '\1', $input);
```

The result should be the exact output of what you have wished for. Check it out here: https://3v4l.org/sbgDX

- `\s*` is to match any white spaces
- `.*?` is a non greedy matching on any characters in between
- `\1*` in the pattern argument means the sub pattern repeated 0 or more, after a line break or any white spaces after the matching pattern

Inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856532/matching-the-same-word-twice-with-a-regular-expression-not-caring-what-the-word).