# Notification alert if word is found more than two times

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a notification if the word 'TEST' appears in the webpage anymore than 2 times. I have this code for alerting whenever the word is found , but am unable to frame the code where the alert is announced if the word appears for more than 2 times. Please help me with this. Thank you in advance

```
if (/TEST/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )
{
    alert ("Word found!");
}
```

**EDIT**
**This code worked**

```
var str = "TEST"; if (str.split("TEST").length > 2)
 {    alert("Word Found")
 }
```

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856532/matching-the-same-word-twice-with-a-regular-expression-not-caring-what-the-word

Comment: You can get the results as a string and then check the length, It should be in multiples of the length of the word you're testing.
if there's more than the original tested length it means you have there more than once

Comment: `if(document.body.innerHTML.split(/TEST/i).length > 2){
    alert("Found")
}
`

Comment: You could put `/TEST/ig` into a variable and call `.test()` on it twice, using `&&` in your if-statement for both results. Since this regular expression is stateful, the second call to `.test()` will check after the last match occurred